# Carregar pagina web em UIWebView Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift-3

Bom dia pessoal

Consigo carregar uma pagina web tranquilamente em uma UIWebView com o seguinte código Swift:

```
import UIKit

class ConteudoOnlineViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var pagina: UIWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    pagina.delegate = self as? UIWebViewDelegate
    if let url = URL(string: "http://www.meusite.com.br/login.aspx") {
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        pagina.loadRequest(request)
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Porém meu site tem pagina de login e criei uma validação para acessar direto passando um token, ocorre que agora não consigo carregar esta pagina na UIWebView, simplesmente não aparece nada. Alguém poderia me dar uma ideia do que devo fazer??

```
import UIKit

class ConteudoOnlineViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var pagina: UIWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    pagina.delegate = self as? UIWebViewDelegate
    if let url = URL(string: "http://www.meusite.com.br/login.aspx?token=6D5C6A4BF468D43ABD521A3C9D3469C3​") {
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        pagina.loadRequest(request)
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

O iOS possui uma camada de segurança chamada App Transport Security (ATS) que por padrão bloqueia conexões inseguras (HTTP). O ideal é implementar a conexão segura no lado do servidor, pois as conexões inseguras podem ser bloqueadas completamente em alguma versão futura do iOS. Caso isso não seja possível, você pode desabilitar essas restrições através do arquivo info.plist do projeto. Sugiro ler a documentação no [portal](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW33) da Apple. No seu caso, provavelmente a configuração necessária é algo como:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>meusite.com.br</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Comment: Rafael Leão obrigado por seu comentário, porém já fiz isso para poder acessar links em http porém não obtenho exito neste caso, ele abre qualquer link porém quando tento dessa forma passando um token para logar direto no sistema nada aparece na webview

Comment: Sugiro então implementar os métodos de UIWebViewDelegate e ver quais são chamados